# write a file to the users desktop in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to write a simple text file from my winform app in c# directly to the user's desktop and not be denied. How can I get the path? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) to get the path to the desktop.  You may need to run elevated to write to this folder.

**Edit:** You also need to ensure that your administrative user has access to the desktop folder.  For example:

[image]

Comment: thanks I used this 'string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);' and it worked .

Comment: @naf-naf This correctly gets the path, but when I Run as admin, I still get Access is Denied. Any idea why, and possible workarounds?

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck, check the folder security by navigating to the desktop folder (e.g., c:\users\myusername\Desktop) and checking the folder properties in Windows Explorer.  If the folder has been marked as not allowing the correct access to the admin user you've run as, you can't write there without changing the folder permissions.